# Dynamic resizing a Gtk.Frame

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

The initial goal is to reduce the height of a frame to hide its lower part. This does not seem to work as long as there are still active widgets in the zone. So I use the 'visible' property to hide these widgets and 'height_request' to manage the height of the frame. The statement

```
self.frSaisie.set_property('height_request', 160)
```

(start Section of the code and in the callback) is totally inoperative. I even tried hiding the box ... still without result.
In addition, the masking works when it is activated by the CheckButton (but not the resizing), but is not taken into account when launching the application (bottom of the code).
If anyone has an idea, thanks in advance.
Sorry for the code length.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk','3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Appli(Gtk.Window):
  def __init__(self):
    Gtk.Window.__init__(self, window_position = 1)
    self.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)

    # wid actifs
    etNom = Gtk.Entry()
    etPrenom = Gtk.Entry()
    btValider = Gtk.Button('Valider')
    btEnregistrer = Gtk.Button('Enregistrer')
    btSupprimer = Gtk.Button('Supprimer')
    btEffacer = Gtk.Button('Effacer')
    self.ckGerer = Gtk.CheckButton('Gérer...', margin = 12)
    self.ckGerer.connect('toggled', self.Gerer)

    # wid container
    gdIdentite = Gtk.Grid(margin = 6)
    self.gdFonctions = Gtk.Grid(margin = 6, halign = 3, row_spacing = 6, column_spacing = 6)
    self.frSaisie = Gtk.Frame(label = '   Saisie   ', margin = 6, height_request = 400)

    # Remplissage Grid
    gdIdentite.attach(Gtk.Label('Nom', xalign = 1,margin_right = 6),0,0,1,1)
    gdIdentite.attach(etNom,1,0,1,1)
    gdIdentite.attach(Gtk.Label('Prénom', xalign = 1,margin_right = 6),0,1,1,1)
    gdIdentite.attach(etPrenom,1,1,1,1)
    self.gdFonctions.attach(btValider,0,0,1,1)
    self.gdFonctions.attach(btEnregistrer,1,0,1,1)
    self.gdFonctions.attach(btSupprimer,0,1,1,1)
    self.gdFonctions.attach(btEffacer,1,1,1,1)

    # Remplissage Box + Frame
    self.bxSaisie = Gtk.Box(orientation = Gtk.Orientation(1))
    self.bxSaisie.pack_start(gdIdentite, False, False, 0)
    self.bxSaisie.pack_start(self.ckGerer, False, False, 0)
    self.bxSaisie.pack_start(self.gdFonctions, True, True, 0)
    self.frSaisie.add(self.bxSaisie)
    self.add(self.frSaisie)

    # Start
    self.gdFonctions.set_property('visible', False) # not running at start
    self.frSaisie.set_property('height_request', 160) # never running
    self.show_all()

  def Gerer(self, etat):
    if self.ckGerer.get_active():
      self.gdFonctions.set_property('visible', True)
    else:
      self.gdFonctions.set_property('visible', False) # running
      self.frSaisie.set_property('height_request', 160) # never running

Appli()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 2):

It works better to resize the top window:

```
  def Gerer(self, etat):
    if self.ckGerer.get_active():
      self.gdFonctions.set_property('visible', True)
    else:
      self.gdFonctions.set_property('visible', False) # running
      self.resize(50, 50) # never running
```

Comment: OK. Thank you for this answer, but it does not work (for me) and then it would not be completely applicable in my case since the code portion given example is a frame that in the real code cohabit with 3 other frames, all in a box, itself a child of a page of Gtk.Notebook ... hence the importance that the resizing only carries the frame concerned.

Comment: @phdb44 Maybe I should say, that width request and height requests makes stuff larger not smaller. If you want to reduce the window size, you need to resize it and/or remove size requests on internal widgets. I have seen this work on very complex windows with lots of widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I worked around the problem using the Gtk.AspectFrame widget. The behavior is what I expected.
I replaced the declaration of the frame:

```
self.frSaisie = Gtk.Frame(label = '   Saisie   ', margin = 6, height_request = 300)
```

by

```
self.frSaisie = Gtk.AspectFrame(label = '   Saisie   ', margin = 6, \
                                    height_request = 100, yalign = 0.001)
```

and I slightly modified the callback to simplify things.

However, I still do not understand why this formatting - now triggered by the function femMini - does not apply to startup.
If anyone could explain to me ... Thank you in advance

```
class Appli(Gtk.Window):
  def __init__(self):
    Gtk.Window.__init__(self, window_position = 1, height_request = 400)
    self.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
    # wid actifs
    etNom = Gtk.Entry()
    etPrenom = Gtk.Entry()
    btValider = Gtk.Button('Valider')
    btEnregistrer = Gtk.Button('Enregistrer')
    btSupprimer = Gtk.Button('Supprimer')
    btEffacer = Gtk.Button('Effacer')
    self.ckGerer = Gtk.CheckButton('Gérer...', margin = 12)
    self.ckGerer.connect('toggled', self.Gerer)
    # wid container
    gdIdentite = Gtk.Grid(margin = 6)
    self.gdFonctions = Gtk.Grid(margin = 6, halign = 3, row_spacing = 6, column_spacing = 6)
    #self.frSaisie = Gtk.Frame(label = '   Saisie   ', margin = 6, height_request = 300)
    self.frSaisie = Gtk.AspectFrame(label = '   Saisie   ', margin = 6, \
                                    height_request = 100, yalign = 0.001)
    # Remplissage Grid
    gdIdentite.attach(Gtk.Label('Nom', xalign = 1,margin_right = 6),0,0,1,1)
    gdIdentite.attach(etNom,1,0,1,1)
    gdIdentite.attach(Gtk.Label('Prénom', xalign = 1,margin_right = 6),0,1,1,1)
    gdIdentite.attach(etPrenom,1,1,1,1)
    self.gdFonctions.attach(btValider,0,0,1,1)
    self.gdFonctions.attach(btEnregistrer,1,0,1,1)
    self.gdFonctions.attach(btSupprimer,0,1,1,1)
    self.gdFonctions.attach(btEffacer,1,1,1,1)
    # Remplissage Box + Frame
    self.bxSaisie = Gtk.Box(orientation = Gtk.Orientation(1))
    self.bxSaisie.pack_start(gdIdentite, False, False, 0)
    self.bxSaisie.pack_start(self.ckGerer, False, False, 0)
    self.bxSaisie.pack_start(self.gdFonctions, True, True, 0)
    self.frSaisie.add(self.bxSaisie)
    self.add(self.frSaisie)

    # Start
    self.fenMini()
    self.show_all()

  # Méthodes
  def fenMini(self):
    self.gdFonctions.set_property('visible', False)
    self.frSaisie.set_property('height_request', 120)

  def fenMaxi(self):
    self.gdFonctions.set_property('visible', True)

  # Callbacks
  def Gerer(self, etat):
    if self.ckGerer.get_active():
      self.fenMaxi()
    else:
      self.fenMini()

Appli()
Gtk.main()
```